# Select filename from file path : invalid perl operator: (?=

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm querying github on BigQuery. I'm trying to use the following regex expression to get the filename from a given file path, i.e.: given `/src/components/App.vue` it should return `App`:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(f.path, r'[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+?(?=\.)') as filename
```

This is giving the error stated in the question title. Is there a workaround I can use to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below instead

```
SELECT f.path, regexp_extract(f.path, r'/([^/.]+).[^.]*$') as filename
```

if applied to sample in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT regexp_extract(f.path, r'([A-Za-z0-9_-]+?)[.]') as filename
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/nLjjQO/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Za-z0-9_-]+?          any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
                             'z', '0' to '9', '_', '-' (1 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [.]                      any character of: '.'
```